# Cocoa Touch display Multiple Currencies

Tags: iphone, cocoa, touch, currency, nslocale

I am using Cocoa Touch to develop an iPhone App.

I am storing currency amounts in a table along with associated Currency Codes From the ISO 4217 Currency Code List :

for example : 123.45 GBP, 456.45 USD, 321.98 AUD etc.

When I am displaying these values I want them to be formatted using the correct Currency Symbol : £ 123.45, $ 456.45, $ 321.98.

For displaying amounts in the current locale I am using

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];                         
[numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numFormatter setLocale: [NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

I want to be able to set up a locale from the Currency Codes to display the correct Currency Symbol.

Is there any way to set up a locale given the Currency Code ?

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use the current locale since it's user-configurable. Instead, just set the currency code:

```
[numFormatter setCurrencyCode: theIOSCurrencyCode];
```

Comment: My app is for people travelling abroad to keep track of their expenses - so I need to keep the current locale set to that of the user's home country.

Comment: @arossco Yes, the current locale is what users set in Settings, General->International, and it doesn't change when you cross the border. When you display a list of prices in various currencies in one and the same locale, the prices are all formatted consistently, according to user preferences. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** fixed a typo

If you really want to change the locale you could store the locale identifiers instead of currency codes in your table and access the data as follows:

```
locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[numFormatter setLocale: locale];
[locale release];
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I'm now storing the Locale identifier with the amount and it is working well !